# Successful import of osm2po results

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po

I would like to know if my import of some osm2po results into a PostgreSQL database have been successful or not.

Is there something like: `Import successful` or a simple `Done`?

All I got was:

`public.eu_2po_4pgr.geom_way SRID:4326 TYPE:LINESTRING DIMS:2
1(row)`

Answer (score 1):

The result you provided was likely generated by a similar command (windows) which has the -q option:

```
C:\>psql -U postgres -d postgres -q -f na_2po_polyrel.sql
```

You can remove the -q option and it will output each command from the file to the screen, however, doing so will not output any kind of "successful" message but you could follow it to determine if all commands were run.  I would assume also that doing do would slow down the process (with many records) because of having to write the results to the screen.

See [How to get notices to the output stream?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23612/how-to-get-notices-to-the-output-stream) for more information about outputting results.

Answer (score 0):

What have you done?
Osm2po takes osm container and generates a tiles and several sql files (depends on config).

Importing sql files to PostgreSQL means just execute

```
psql database < osm_2po_....sql
```

Result of this import does not differs from another postgres import.
As I recall, all osm2po sql files ends with index creation.
So, of you see, that some index created - all fine.